# How do you use the output of projectPoints()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, graphics

I'm using the projectPoints() method in openCV to get a 2D array from 3D.

I now have a 2D array, but I have no idea of what to do with the points...

This probably sounds like a dumb question but I'm very new to openCV and working with graphics in general.

I've saved the points as a .txt file, and it looks like this:

```
[[[ 200.09907914  -82.06738337]]

 [[ 493.43350608  -75.61411136]]

 [[ 341.84147575  -76.85033738]]

 [[ 476.1858408   -44.00185036]]

 [[ 388.80711654  -23.52747913]]

 [[ 419.89479852  -80.92570616]]

 [[ 270.18706415  -78.77744771]]

 [[ 453.17295132  -38.22746564]]

 [[ 336.55951175  -78.23490512]]

 [[ 461.80562252  -50.39816719]]

 [[ 400.55422812  -69.06144546]]

 [[ 377.27021722  -30.25844784]]

 [[ 269.73447838  -81.67956696]]

 [[ 204.3975581   -64.63087857]]

 [[ 322.0647573   -50.91627825]]

 [[ 264.52576218  -62.21001649]]

 [[ 343.94977452  -18.27828932]]

 [[ 424.40214827  -19.53042058]]

 [[ 529.80110569  -30.70642375]]

 [[ 426.91725443  -19.8445123 ]]

 [[ 382.43526019  -16.33614303]]

 [[ 575.52868617  -29.50400229]]
    etc...

    [[ 180.53274111  319.29471839]]]
[[ -41.8973341   457.25621412  238.56738337 ...,   83.7946682   169.35134067
    -2.55510041]
 [-571.8835458    41.8973341   -77.90092086 ...,  398.60600403   83.7946682
    -7.82485769]
 [ 112.73208124  548.20593581  232.11411136 ..., -225.46416248
   435.35288301   28.52750401]
 ..., 
 [-499.21204508  -49.92094479 -140.9565395  ...,  211.70278173
   -99.84188958    1.82323202]
 [  35.77105875  464.99179761 -162.79471839 ...,  -71.5421175   123.99637881
    -0.59708278]
 [-503.32183347  -35.77105875  -97.46725889 ...,  200.65645054  -71.5421175
     0.9972777 ]]
```

Comment: what's the question? The output of projectPoints are projected points. Looks like all your points are not projected to the image area (negative coordinates). Are you sure that the 3D positions should be visible on the image and that your camera intrinsics and extriniscs were chosen correctly before projection?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I'm using PhotoScan to export the objects and camera calibrations. I'm trying to create a temporal viewer to see the changes in a scene over a time period. I've been told that using projectPoints() will create a 2D array that I can make an image out of, for each time-frame.

My problem is that I don't really know what to put in to get the 2D array. I have a file of exported 'points' (v & vn) and also an object file (v, vn, vt and f). I don't know what to use :(

Comment: Six years later, I too am wondering why the output is three-dimensional and not 2D. However, I (perhaps naively) believe we can simply ignore that additional dimension  by doing `imagePoints = np.squeeze(imagePoints)`